# How to use a While loop into a button for a post?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button and I can't figure out what syntax is holding me back in making the value from a row being put into this statement.

```
<?php 
print "
<a class='btn btn-default btn-xs' role='button' href ='edit_questions.php?action=check_answers&questionID=$row[questionID]_$auditID'>Edit</a>
"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'echo' to display data in PHP.
Try the following:

```
<?php 
    echo "<a class='btn btn-default btn-xs' role='button' href='edit_questions.php?action=check_answers&questionID=".$row[questionID]."_".$auditID."'>Edit</a>";
?>
```